# Best practices using PhpUnit

Tags: phpunit

I'm new with PhpUnit, and I have some doubts on best practices writing tests.

My first test is as following:

```
<?php

require_once '../Scrap.php';

class ScrapTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $scrap;

    // Setup function to instantiate de object to $this->scrap
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->scrap = new Scrap;
    }

    /**
    * @covers Scrap::getPhone
    *
    */
    public function testGetPhone() {

        // Variables
        $array_static1 = Array(0 => 218559372, 1 => 927555929, 2 => 213456789, 3 => 912345678);
        $phone_list1   = '</div>A Front para<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />-Apoio;<br />-Criação;<br />-Campanhas;<br />-Promoções<br /><br /><br />CONDIÇÕES:<br /><br />Local de Trabalho: Es<br />Folgas: Mistas<br /><br /><br /><br />ordem 500€<br /><br /><br /><br />Mínimos:<br /><br />- Conhecimentos;<br />- Ensino ;<br />-INGLÊS.<br /><br /><br /><br />Candidaturas: <br />email@ffff.es<br />218559372 | 927 555 929 | <br />RH<br />Rua C. Sal. 40<br />1000-000 Lisboa<br /><br /><br />+351 21 3456789 | (351) 912345678';

        $this->assertEquals($array_static1, $this->scrap->getPhone($phone_list1, '351', '9'));
    }
}
?>
```

Can I do beter than this? Is this the correct way of doing it?

If you can give me some clues I would be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would use [dataProvider](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) feature of phpUnit in this case. That will allow you to have simple, clean test case and additional method with different test data sets.

Example:

```
public function getTextsAndPhones() {
    return array(
        array(
           '</div>A Front para<br /><br />(...)<br />+351 21 3456789 | (351) 912345678',
            array(0 => 218559372, 1 => 927555929, 2 => 213456789, 3 => 912345678),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider getTextsAndPhones
 */
public function testGetPhone( $text, $phones ) {
    $this->assertEquals($phones, $this->scrap->getPhone($text, '351', '9'));
}
```

Of course you can include '351' and '9' parameters in the data provider as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the fixture (the HTML that will be injected), from a file, using file_get_contents. It's a bit mess having a long HTML string.

Also, it's convenient having clear variable names. In your case, $array_static1 could be renamed to $expected_phone_numbers.